# Passing arguments to trigger function in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, triggers

I had two tables `table1` and `table2`.

`table1` has three entries - `id primary key`, `fd foreign key(table2)`, `val_t1`

`table2` has 2 entries - `fd primary key`, `val_t2`

If `val_t1` of any row in the `table1` is updated, it should trigger a function with the corresponding value of `fd` field as an argument. This `fd` should be used in the trigger function to get the corresponding `val_t2` from the `table2`.

I have read about `TG_ARGV` but unable to use it in the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need arguments, the value is in the `new` record, example:

```
create or replace function trigger_on_table1()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare
    val text;
begin
    select val_t2 into val
    from table2
    where fd = new.fd;
    raise notice '%', val;
    return new;
end;
$$
```